# Uninstallation Script in NSIS

Tags: installation, nsis

I am a newbie in writing an installer/uninstaller. I need an uninstaller to delete the files stored in the log file (text file). I am trying to implement the functionality using NSIS script but I couldn't though I followed the below link :
http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Talk:Uninstall_only_installed_files
Basically I need to implement the following four lines of code:

```
OutFile "dummy.exe" 
Section "Uninstall"
!include "unlist.txt"
!system 'del unlist.txt'
SectionEnd
```

The include statement shows an error as I've appended the file names with wrong format in unlist.txt .

Compilation result:

```
OutFile: "dummy.exe"
Section: "Uninstall"
!include: "unlist.txt"
File: "Test1.txt" [compress] 4 bytes
File: "Test2.txt" [compress] 0/4 bytes
File: "Test3.txt" [compress] 0/4 bytes
File: "Test4.txt" [compress] 0/4 bytes
!include: closed: "unlist.txt"
SectionEnd
```

Processed 1 file, writing output:

```
Error: invalid script: no sections specified
Error - aborting creation process
```

Can anyone advise me with a correct script or the correct format of file need to be mentioned in the unlist.txt ?

Thanks for your help.

Best Regards,
Peter

Answer (score 4):

Your installer need to look at least like this:

```
OutFile "dummy.exe"

Section 01
# This is install section
WriteUninstaller "Uninstall.exe"
SectionEnd

Section "Uninstall"
!include "unlist.txt"
!system 'del unlist.txt'
SectionEnd
```

One install section must exists and simple uninstaller is created (in temp directory).
You need to specify more code to work correctly: e.g. set $INSTDIR etc.